# Add Superscript to price decimal display

Tags: price, catalog, magento2.4.4

I want to change the HTML formatting of the price across the entire frontend. Is there a possible way to add `<sup>` tag to price decimals in Magento displayed all across the website?

The current HTML return is:
$3.000

Want to show it as
$3.<sup>000</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and check.

One way to do this is by creating a custom module and using the event **`"catalog_block_product_price"`** to modify the price rendering.

Here is an example of how you can add the **`<sup>`** tag to the price decimals:

Create a new module by creating the following files and folders:

- app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php
- app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml
- app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml
- app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/DecimalPrice.php

Now create **`registration.php`** file and add the following code:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

Now create the **`module.xml`** file and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

Now create the **`events.xml`** file and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_block_product_price">
        <observer name="vendor_module_decimal_price" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\DecimalPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now create the **`DecimalPrice.php`** file and add the following code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class DecimalPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        $price = $block->getPrice();
        $priceArray = explode(".", $price);
        $priceArray[1] = '<sup>' . $priceArray[1] . '</sup>';
        $price = implode(".", $priceArray);
        $block->setPrice($price);
    }
}
```

Run the following command to enable the module:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

This code will add the  tag to the price decimals for all prices displayed on the website.

**`UPDATED`**

1. Create a new module in **`app/code/[Vendor]/[ModuleName]`**
2. Create a new file in the module's **`view/frontend/layout`** directory named **`catalog_product_prices.xml`**
3. In the **`catalog_product_prices.xml`** file, add the following code:

Here is the code:-

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="default_price_render_template" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]_[ModuleName]::product/price/amount/default.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

4. Create a new file in the module's **`view/frontend/templates/product/price/amount`** directory named **`default.phtml`**
5. In the **`default.phtml`** file, replace the existing code for displaying the price decimal with the following:

Here is the code:-

```
<sup class="decimal"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatCurrency($priceModel->getAmount() - $priceModel->getInteger(), $priceModel->getCurrency()) ?></sup>
```

6. In the module's **`etc/module.xml`** file, add the following code:

Here is the code:-

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[Vendor]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

7. In the module's **`registration.php`** file, add the following code:

Here is the code:-

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[Vendor]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

8. Run the following command to enable the module:

Here is command:-

```
php bin/magento module:enable [Vendor]_[ModuleName]
```

9. Run the following command to upgrade the database schema and data:

Here is command:-

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

10. Clear your cache

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Thanks for your code and suggestion. Unfortunately, this hasn't done the trick the `sup` isn't added to the price

Comment: First please check your Observer call or not?

Comment: I checked it seems not ... not sure what might be the reason, any suggestions? I found a solution by overriding the `default.phtml` file based on your code ever tried it?

Comment: See my update answer. I have override file and add sup tag.

Comment: Hello ... I applied your answer a while ago and it worked however it works only for simple products. While configurable products on a page load it shows the subscript once load is finished it turns back to its original view

Comment: P.S. same happens to Single Product Page